# OOZIE CRON Scheduler

Tags: cron, oozie

How to get list of next materialized times for oozie coordinator if we have scheduled it frequency using CRON.
In HUE i can see the next materialized time only, I want a list of all the time it will run.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Oozie doesn't give you that list nor provide tools to calculate it. 
I usually convert my expression CRON syntax and check with this  http://www.cronmaker.com/. This is not a solid answer to your question but at least gives you the execution frequency.

rest syntax

```
curl http://www.cronmaker.com/rest/sampler?expression={expression}
```

sample with rest api

```
http://www.cronmaker.com/rest/sampler?expression=0%200/2%20*%201/1%20*%20?%20*
```